# how i can cancel a transaction in blockchain,info?

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions

I have two transaction of bitcoin that i sent about 12 hours ago now i want to cancel it or to confirm it how can i do it?

because the other part that i have sent my other bitcoins does not pay my money

[2c4d2b4cae5613ff2fbab071a4804b25ac32ba0c65cf30a506c9b691a7ccdf63](https://blockchain.info/tx/2c4d2b4cae5613ff2fbab071a4804b25ac32ba0c65cf30a506c9b691a7ccdf63)

[e5ea6688bec80f31e431643580c1f5f13cdf52ddafd5ed6ee6ca483fee8c133e](https://blockchain.info/tx/e5ea6688bec80f31e431643580c1f5f13cdf52ddafd5ed6ee6ca483fee8c133e)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of canceling a transaction once you publish it to the network.

At the moment there are many transactions (about [100k](https://mempool.observer)) waiting to be confirmed. This might take a while.

For now the best thing you can do is to wait.